# Asking for an approch to start building an Analysis app for top management industrial company

Tags: r, django, shiny

I want your suggestions to start a simple software developement.
I'm an intern student and i want to build, preferably, something that can be acceced with a user authentication to a specific number of users < 5 so that each one of them can access the analysis of the data that concerns him. Preferably :

- I want my users to get to the app through the browser
- The users are those who will provide data to the app through an upload file button so this latter can output the whole analysis
- the app should have a professional look

I'm supposed to work with these four-five peapole to determine what they want to see so i can prepare all the analysis code that corresponds to the right feeded data. genrally the data will have csv excel format.

I've start working with R shiny then I built a single shiny app for control and mangement director that contains a dahsboard with analysis/viZ elements. Then i figured out that I cannot add the feature of multiple users and neither the authotication feature. then I've start learning django but i realized that it's quite harder to do it in a month. I searched for django-plotly-library but I always hesitate to work and learn until the end.

well, now i'm open to learn anything that can solve this issue. I've been hesitating for a month to choose the right technology. I appreciate your suggestions and remarks.

Comment: The question is all over the place. So you want Django or no?

Comment: from your response i can say that it's possible with django. if yes, how can I do it as much quikly as possible without following the official documentation tutorial ? 
I'm used to work with python on data science and deep learning project but I'm not initiated to all the web/server world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django User's Guide gives you most of the answers, mainly regarding the authentication. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/
Corey Schafer does high quality videos, here on the authentication:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4jPR-M0TAQ
For the professional look : bootstrap + django-crispy-forms, it's very convenient.
To upload data: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs6dXL9Wp7s&t=882s

Comment: by uploading data i meant i should give the ability to the users to for exmaple click on button then import a csv file that respects some constraints so it can be traited inside the app, thank you very much

Comment: exactly : afterward you can create a view which automates the function.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really answers. Also, the original question is 100% opinion-soliciting. Not something that should be answered here, as it's not something that can be answered objectively. Note that it's also a tool/product/service recommendation question, also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Django it is completely possible to modify data served to each user. You can do it with the use of permissions or even with the use of front technologies such as filtering data.

"the app should have a professional look" is such a general statement I don't think there is anything to be suggested. If you want for this app to look "professional" you can try using some react templates such as react-admin.

Django has builtin auth system  and it is highly configurable. But if you want that "industry standard" frontend you should write your backend in DRF and add React/Vue/Svelte etc.